# Meaning of one sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

**The obligation to write it is all in one's own eyes.**

It's difficult to understand.

Comment: Do you have any additional context for that sentence? A guess could be made at it's meaning, but it sounds like it's a piece of self-help advice and what "write it" is referring to is impossible to decipher without context.

Comment: 'You're beating yourself up, thinking that you _have_ to write it.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best exercise when failing to truly fathom a sentence is to parse it into its corresponding heads and phrases.

"The obligation to write it is all in one's own eyes." 
Firstly, the agent, 'obligation' is the relatum of the copula 'is all in one's own eyes'. The phrase 'to write it' is a verbal phrase describing what the obligation is. 
Ultimately, 'in one's own eyes' may be translated as 'relative to one's perspective/feelings'.

Therefore, the sentence is suggesting that the duty involved in writing (it) is based on one's perspective.